# Popen subprocess does not work inside a SublimeREPL?

Tags: python, r, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I use `conda` to create a Python 2.7 environment including the [R package](https://www.r-project.org/). If I open a Python session in a console, I can check that `R` is indeed installed with the [Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) constructor:

```
$ python
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> proc = Popen(["which", "R"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
>>> proc.wait()
0
```

where the `0` means it is installed. But if I try the same commands from within a [Sublime Text 3 REPL](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) running under the exact same Python environment, I get a `1`.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to communicate:

```
proc = Popen(['which', 'python'], stdout=PIPE)
proc.communicate()

('/Users/Kelvin/virtualenvs/foo/bin/python\n', None)
```

`wait` just waits for the subprocess to complete and gives you the return code (which is 0 if its successful)

if you get a different error code (1 meaning it failed), I'd look into confirming your virtual environment.  try `sys.executable`

Comment: In  a Python session `proc.communicate()` returns: `('/home/gabriel/anaconda3/envs/asteca27/bin/R\n', '')`. In a REPL it returns `('', '')`. So I guess it is not detecting `R` installed in the `anaconda3` environment from the REPL, even with `communicate()`.

Comment: It might be that if you're doing it from your repl (which is it, spyder, jupyter, else?) that it isn't writing to stdout but back to whatever the repl is so its coming back blank?  I'm not sure about that last part to be honest.

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text 3. Thanks anyway, `communicate()` is useful.